# Index Attribute resolving issue in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, annotations, visual-studio-2019

I have got .Net Standart 2.0 dll to keep separated entities of MS SQL Server.

The `Index Attribute` cannot be resolving.

**I've did search and experimented with adding some namespaces of Entity Framework but nothing works even by [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations).**

Please, help. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations - see the note: "Configuring indexes via Data Annotations has been introduced in EF Core 5.0." (and you have EF Core 3.1.19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IndexAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.indexattribute?view=efcore-5.0)

> Specifies an index to be generated in the database.
>
> **Entity Framework Core**
>
> - 5.0

You are not using EF core 5. You will need to use the model Builder instead

---

Read more here

[Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations)

> Configuring indexes via Data Annotations has been introduced in EF
> Core 5.0.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasIndex(b => b.Url);
}
```

Comment: I've restored database model via `Scaffold-DbContext` so what is the correct solution to do it properly to get  the `model Builder` syntax? I don't like to manualy change the code evrey time I've update the model...

Comment: @DmitryBoyko this is part of your DBContext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: @DmitryBoyko you could upgrade to core 5 :) honestly I don't know the answer that particular question of how to persist modal builder changes on when updating form a db

Comment: It is unclear what is the solution you offer... Would you mind to detail it in your answer please? Thank you!

Comment: Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.10 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.10 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/40535/please-tell-me-when-will-uwp-support-net-standard.html I am frustrated as well... There is no solution yet...

Comment: @DmitryBoyko can you not upgrade t0 efcore 5.0 and your library to .net standard 2.1 ?